# Fluent NHibernate and NHibernate.Linq Mono

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, mono, fluent-nhibernate, monodevelop

I'm currently moving a project to linux using Monodevelop, MVC3 and FluentNhibernate. My issue is the the linq to Nhibernate using the Method Syntax:

```
var payment = session.Query<PaymentInfo>().Where(c => c.AccountId == newPayment.AccountId).FirstOrDefault();
```

Mono develop doesn't seem to recognize the properties of "c". Is this normal behaviour? I have the same issue with the Query Syntax:

```
var payment = (from c in session.Query<PaymentInfo>()
             where c.AccountId == newPayment.AccountId
             select c).FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? I have the Nhibernate.dll and System.Data* libraries but it just doesn't seem to want to work. Should I be using Criteria's?

**EDIT:** It actually looks like the mapping aren't being picked up. Is FluentNhibernate unsupported? I'm not sure if the issue is Mono or just within Monodevelop itself as I'd like to be able to test in Linux. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: the lambda syntax should have nothing to do with NHibernate, it is a compiler feature. try `new PaymentInfo[0].Where(c => c.AccountId == newPayment.AccountId).FirstOrDefault()` to see if the compiler complains there too

Comment: It was complaining, but I solved it by removing and readding the libraries, not really sure why that worked, and that bothers me :/

Comment: My project is compiling now, but I'm getting an error saying       [System.Exception: Method not found: 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_ConfigurationFactory']

Comment: I guess it's because as default some library tries to access app.config. There's probably a way to configure that once you showed the stracktrace to see which library does it

Comment: @Firo, I've posted a seperate question with the new stack trace: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822741/mono-couldnt-bind-to-method-sethostingenvironment

Comment: Please refer to my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842290/fluentnhibernate-typeloadexception/14863564#14863564